# Replace file names with their md5 hashes

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I've the next list of files:

```
 ~$: find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
 2a1731ae57fb17659b21f180f9fcbebd  ./temp.rd1
 f792fb6f13996a91d1ccbe2a8e3242fc  ./temp2.rd1
 f792fb6f13996a91d1ccbe2a8e3242fc  ./older1/temp.rd2
 b69997ffce70ec116b7f46eabdfc7040  ./older1/sub/temp.rd1
 d757a18d4a3c11c2a9a45e2f3815d3a1  ./older2/temp.rd3
 d79cc7e5f45852b79ddc896cc8e2b58c  ./older3/temp.rd3
```

The left column contains md5 sums of a files presented in right column. I need to rename files with next way:

```
 ./2a1731ae57fb17659b21f180f9fcbebd.rd1
 ./f792fb6f13996a91d1ccbe2a8e3242fc.rd1
 ./older/f792fb6f13996a91d1ccbe2a8e3242fc.rd2
 ./older/sub/b69997ffce70ec116b7f46eabdfc7040.rd1
 ./older2/d757a18d4a3c11c2a9a45e2f3815d3a1.rd3
 ./older3/d79cc7e5f45852b79ddc896cc8e2b58c.rd3
```

I'm tring to complete this with sed:

```
 sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\(\..*\)\)$/mv -v \2 \1\3/e'
```

This renames files but directories in paths are lost, so I'm looking for a correct way to do this (with sed or awk).

Comment: `$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "${1%.*}.$(md5 -q $1).${1##*.}"' bash {} \;
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^\s*(\S+)\s*((\.(/[^/]*)*/)[^.]*(\..*))|mv \2 \3\1\5|e' file
```

Rearrange each line using back references and then evaluate the command produced.

N.B. Perhaps a safer way is to remove the `e` flag and capture the output in a file. Then pipe the file to the shell after inspection.

Comment: Great job. That's when RegEx can get really complex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` for an easier solution:

I created an extra `.sh` file for this job:

```
#!/bin/sh
MD5=$(md5sum "$1" | awk '{print $1'})
DIR=${1%/*}
FN=${1##*/}
EXT=${FN##*.}

if [ -n "$EXT" ]; then
    mv "$1" "$DIR/${MD5}.$EXT"
else
    mv "$1" "$DIR/${MD5}"
fi
```

Save it and `chmod 777`, then you just run

```
find . -type f -exec rename-file.sh {} \;
```